# Nonclosed union of tetrahedra in CGAL

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

I have two tetrahedra T1 and T2 and I compute their union with CGAL. This is the result:

[image]

Quite nice. To compute the union, I convert the tetrahedra to nefs and I use the union operator `+`.

But now, I have a third tetrahedron T3, and I would like to compute the union of T1, T2 and T3. That does not work. It seems that the problem is that T1+T2 is not closed (`is_closed()` returns `false`).

What does that mean exactly that a polyhedron is not closed? I don't see what is not "closed" in the above picture. And is there a way to close T1+T2 in order that I can perform the union, or something else to solve this issue?

Comment: What kernel are you using?

Comment: Hello @Sneftel. Thank you for your attention. In fact I have solved my problem now. My error was to convert the nef T1*T2 to a surface mesh. Now I apply T1*T2*T3 to the three tetrahedra. To answer your question, I use the "exact" kernel (`Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel`). I don't manage to deal with nefs with another kernel.

Comment: You should post that as an answer!